# Stata - reading a limited number of variables from a large dataset

Tags: stata

I'm working with Stata IC 13 and need to do different types of analysis on different variables of a large dataset.The problem is that my dataset is very large so I get the following error

> Up to 2,048 variables are allowed with this version of Stata

Is there a way to name the variables you want to import to work around this problem (using Stata, not other programs)?

I need a flexible way of importing variables by variable names, rather than having to split my original dataset in lots of little subsets. I've heard of [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855087/stata-transferring-datasets-to-dta-format-when-number-of-variables-exceeds-the), but I'm relatively new to Stata  so I would be very grateful if anyone could show me code examples of how they get around this limit on a daily basis.

Let's take a silly example. Let's say I want to import only the variables pared and public from this dataset.

```
use http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/ologit.dta, clear
```

How would you do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`help use` spells out that optionally you can specify variable names with `use`:

Load subset of Stata-format dataset

```
   . use [varlist] [if] [in] using filename [, clear nolabel]
```

and there are examples in the help too. So, in your example,

```
  . use pared public using http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/ologit.dta, clear
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had got confused between the commands using and use. I'll try to read the help page more carefully next time.

Comment: `using` isn't a command. It is a key word used within various other commands.